# Possible to create a @synchronized decorator that's aware of a method's object?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a @synchronized wrapper that creates one Lock per object and makes method calls thread safe. I can only do this if I can access method.im_self of the method in the wrapped method.

```
    class B:
        def f(self): pass

    assert inspect.ismethod( B.f ) # OK
    assert inspect.ismethod( B().f ) # OK
    print B.f    # <unbound method B.f>
    print B().f  # <bound method B.f of <__main__.B instance at 0x7fa2055e67e8>>



    def synchronized(func):
        # func is not bound or unbound!
        print func  # <function f at 0x7fa20561b9b0>    !!!!

        assert inspect.ismethod(func)  # FAIL
        # ... allocate one lock per C instance
        return func

    class C:
        @synchronized
        def f(self): pass
```

(1) What's confusing is that the func parameter passed to my decorator changes type before it gets passed into the wrapper-generator. This seem is rude and unnecessary. Why does this happen?

(2) Is there some decorator magic by which I can make method calls to an object mutex-ed (i.e. one lock per object, not per class).

UPDATE: There are many examples of @synchronized(lock) wrappers. However, really what I want is @synchronized(self). I *can* solve it like this:

```
    def synchronizedMethod(func):
        def _synchronized(*args, **kw):
             self = args[0]
             lock = oneLockPerObject(self)
             with lock: return func(*args, **kw)
        return _synchronized
```

However, because its much more efficient, I'd prefer:

```
    def synchronizedMethod(func):
        lock = oneLockPerObject(func.im_self)

        def _synchronized(*args, **kw):
             with lock: return func(*args, **kw)

        return _synchronized
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go read:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/tree/develop/blog

and in particular:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/blob/develop/blog/07-the-missing-synchronized-decorator.md
- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/blob/develop/blog/08-the-synchronized-decorator-as-context-manager.md

The `wrapt` module then contains the `@synchronized` decorator described there.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrapt

The full implementation is flexible enough to do:

```
@synchronized # lock bound to function1
def function1():
    pass 

@synchronized # lock bound to function2
def function2():
    pass 

@synchronized # lock bound to Class
class Class(object):  

    @synchronized # lock bound to instance of Class
    def function_im(self):
        pass 

    @synchronized # lock bound to Class
    @classmethod
    def function_cm(cls):
        pass

    @synchronized # lock bound to function_sm
    @staticmethod
    def function_sm():
        pass
```

Along with context manager like usage as well:

```
class Object(object):  

    @synchronized
    def function_im_1(self):
        pass  

    def function_im_2(self):
        with synchronized(self):
            pass
```

Further information and examples can also be found in:

- http://wrapt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html

There is also a conference talk you can watch on how this is implemented at:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB6AH-85zfY&t=1s

Comment: remember to use `decorator` from `wrapt` module

Answer (score 7):

You can't get `self` at decoration time because the decorator is applied at function definition time. No `self` exists yet; in fact, the *class* doesn't exist yet.

If you're willing to store your lock *on the instance* (which is arguably where a per-instance value should go) then this might do ya:

```
def synchronized_method(func):
    def _synchronized(self, *args, **kw):
         if not hasattr(self, "_lock"): self._lock = oneLockPerObject(self)
         with self._lock: return func(self, *args, **kw)
    return _synchronized
```

You could also generate the lock in your `__init__()` method on a base class of some sort, and store it on the instance in the same way. That simplifies your decorator because you don't have to check for the existence of the `self._lock` attribute.

Comment: This is the better answer, IMO.   It's safer, and fits more use cases than a decorators that often assume global locks.

Comment: Minor typo, but it should be `hasattr`

Answer (score 5):

> (1) What's confusing is that the func parameter passed to my decorator
>   changes type before it gets passed into the wrapper-generator. This
>   seem is rude and unnecessary. Why does this happen?

It doesn't!  Rather, function objects (and other descriptors) produce their `__get__`'s results when that method of theirs is called -- and **that** result is the method object!

But what lives in the `class`'s `__dict__` is always the descriptor -- specifically, the **function** object!  Check it out...:

```
>>> class X(object):
...   def x(self): pass
... 
>>> X.__dict__['x']
<function x at 0x10fe04e60>
>>> type(X.__dict__['x'])
<type 'function'>
```

See?  No method objects around anywhere **at all**!-)

Therefore, no `im_self` around either, at decoration time -- and you'll need to go with your introspection-based alternative idea.

Comment: Thank -- helpful. Why does the language generate unbound methods from functions? Why not just always have an unbound method? This seems to also prevent per-class synchronization.

Comment: @user48956, in Python 3 (ever since 3.0) there are only **bound** methods -- **unbound** ones have been removed from the language, so that just the _two_ types, functions and bound-methods, can do it all more simply.  I.e, the design back in the ancient days of Python 2.0 (15 years ago) was more complicated than necessary.  However, the improvement in 3.0 was far more of a simplification than what you suggest, and won't help you in the least in pursuing the approach you'd favor (even if your decorator's arg *was* an unbound method, its `im_self` would be `None`, so, no help at all anyway!-).